# Existence of smooth vector fields that complement a distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold $M$ and $X_1,\dots,X_k$ smooth vector fields on an open set $U$ of $M$ such that they are linearly independent in every point in $U$.

It is not difficult to show that for every $m\in U$ there are an open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $m$ and smooth vector fields $X_{k+1},\dots,X_{n}$ defined in $V$ such that $\{X_1(p),\dots,X_n(p)\}$ is a basis of $T_pM$ for all $p\in V$.

> Is is possible to find smooth vector fields $X_{k+1},\dots,X_n$
> **defined in the whole open set $U$** such that $\{X_1(p),\dots,X_n(p)\}$ is a basis of $T_pM$ for all $p\in U$?

I guess this is not true, but I cannot find any counterexample.

Comment: Is choosing $U=M$ not admissible? E.g. one can consider $U=M=S^5$.

Comment: Yes, $U=M$ is admissible, though $U=S^2$ will contradicts the hypothesis on $X_1,\dots,X_k$ since there is no smooth vector field in $S^2$ that never vanishes.